# Animating a box with CSS3

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I need to animate a falling box with CSS3. The box should be in the middle of the screen. It should begin the animation from the top, off the screen and reach 25px from the bottom. I tried this:

```
.box {
    width : 112px;
    height : 112px;
    background : url(images/gift_box_small.png) no-repeat;
    margin : auto;
    z-index : 4;
    position : relative;

    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation : box_fall 8s linear 1;

    /* Standard syntax */
    animation: box_fall 8s linear 1;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes box_fall {
    0%   {top:-112px;}
    100% {bottom:25px}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes box_fall {
    0%   {top:-112px;}
    100% {bottom:25px}
}
```

but the animation didn't start. What can be the reason for that and how can I make it work? Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hpsxrjzL/

Thank you!

Comment: The `animation` does work for me (though the start and end positions aren't exactly matching your needs) without any change.

Comment: @Harry That's strange... I'm testing it in FF and it doesn't start there.

Comment: I was testing in Chrome. Maybe you need `-moz-keyframes` and `-moz-animation`. Does the other cloud animations work?

Comment: @Harry Yes, the cloud animations work just fine. Just can't make that box be animated as needed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best way would be to animate the same property instead of combination of two (so for example, animate `top` from start value to end value, instead of starting from `top` and ending with `bottom` - this might be open to cross-browser issues). Something like:

```
@keyframes box_fall {
    0%   {top:-15%;}
    100% {top: 80%;}
}
```

I used percentages in case you don't know the screen size (which is probably why you used `bottom` in the first place). Tweak the numbers a bit and it should be fine.

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/hpsxrjzL/1/

---

Update

In order to make sure the box always lands on the ground, it has to be changed to absolute position with proper centering:

```
left: 0;
top: auto;
bottom: 25px; /* the end position */
right: 0;
```

And then, it's simply about animating it from the top:

```
@keyframes box_fall {
  0%   {bottom: 100%;}
  100% {bottom: 25px;}
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/hpsxrjzL/7/

Comment: I tried this approach too, but the problem is when the screen size is small (for example horizontal mobile phone screen) the box falls beneath the screen, and I need it to stop exactly in the middle of the "ground" div.

Comment: Hmm, and how about animating it from, say, `bottom: 110%` to `bottom: 0%` (again, those numbers probably need a little tweaking)?

Comment: Forgot to mention: the number 1 at the end is not a delay, it's a number of iterations - I want it to be played only 1 time.

Comment: Ah, yes, figured it out after I wrote my answer but was too lazy to edit. :)

Comment: You have an error in your layout - bottom 0 is not what you think, it's actually about where the clouds end. Here is the proper way to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/hpsxrjzL/5/

Comment: Yup, thought about it, trying to change some properties here. Tried to change to `position: absolute; bottom: 25px` - still don't see the animation, the box is no longer in the middle, but the box is 25px from the bottom.

Comment: See my updated answer. `margin: auto` no longer works because of absolute position so you need to set `left` and `right` to 0. Everything looks fine in my Chrome/Ubuntu.

Comment: If you know the box height, do this: top: calc(100% - boxSize - padding) or top: calc(100vh - boxSize - padding)

Comment: @PinhasHouri You can't do that in plain CSS (the variable), and besides I think OP said the point was that the box starts from above the visible area.

Comment: Yes you can, and I was referring to his problem with the end point. Somehow this calc isn't well known, and it saved me so much time. so many edits things become irrelevant :)

Comment: Ah, sorry. I was looking from the bottom... But bottom 100% and bottom 25px is exactly what OP wanted. Is that right, @Igal?

Comment: Well, I wanted it to start just off the screen (initially I thought about -112px, at it's the height of the box img), and end 25px from the bottom. Meanwhile I figured out some workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/hpsxrjzL/9/

Comment: How's that different from what I gave you in the answer 10 minutes ago? http://jsfiddle.net/hpsxrjzL/7/ Except you're setting the left value in the animation.

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't see that update. Your solution is actually better, as it doesn't use any wrapper div, meaning less code to load. Great answer! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Haha, I was surprised when you didn't respond to that answer because it was exactly what you were looking for. :) You're welcome!